# What function satisfies the following: $f(\alpha + \beta x)=f(x)\, \cdot \, g(\alpha,\beta)+h(\alpha,\beta)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

The question is pretty much self-explanatory. I am looking for a function $f(\cdot)$ that satisfies the following condition:

$$f(\alpha + \beta x)=f(x)\, \cdot \, g(\alpha,\beta)+h(\alpha,\beta)$$

Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants. While $g(\alpha,\beta)$ and $h(\alpha,\beta)$ can be functions of either/both or neither $\alpha$, $\beta$. Importantly $g(\alpha,\beta)$ and $h(\alpha,\beta)$ cannot depend on $x$.

Trivially $f(x)=c x$, where $c$ is some constant, satisfies the above condition. But are there other functions that do so? How can I go about identifying them?

Comment: take $f=g=h=0$.

Comment: $f$ constant, $g=1$, $h=0$

Comment: Can you please give more details on $f$, $g$, $h$, $\alpha$, $\beta$?

Comment: Sure, let me edit it once more.

Comment: What is the point of this question?